# checking image dimensions before ajax post event in javascript

Tags: javascript, ajax

I am attempting to access the dimensions from my uploaded image before I post it to the post upload endpoint. If you look, there is a `variable issueArrived` that is supposed to determine if the image is too small and if so negate the upload process. **Unfortunately, the image doesn't access the dimensions check until after the upload to the server commences**. Any help would be appreciated.

```
// internal function that creates an input element
var file = newElement("input", 0, "");

// sets the input element as type file
file.type = "file";
file.multiple = "multiple";
file.name = "photoupload[]";
file.accept = "image/*";

var issueArrived = false;
file.onchange = function(e) {
    // internal function that creates an image element
    var img = newElement("img", 0, "");
    img.onload = function(){
       var cw = img.width;
       var ch = img.height;
       if(cw < 500 || ch < 500) {
         alert("Photo must be atleast 500x500");
         issueArrived = true;
         return false;
       }           
   }
   img.src = URL.createObjectURL(this);
   if (issueArrived) return;
   var formdata = new FormData();
   formdata.append("photoupload[]", this);
   var x = new XMLHttpRequest();
   x.open("POST", "/media/uploadphotos", true);
   x.send(formdata);
}
file.click();
```

Answer (score 0):

onchange method is async. You can't expect to set the value from issueArrived inside it an access it outside.

You can rewrite this way:

```
file.onchange=function(e){
    // internal function that creates an image element
    var img=newElement("img",0,"");
    img.onload=function(){
       var cw=img.width;
       var ch=img.height;
       if(cw<500||ch<500){
         alert("Photo must be atleast 500x500");
       } else {
        var formdata=new FormData();
        formdata.append("photoupload[]",this);
        var x=new XMLHttpRequest();
        x.open("POST","/media/uploadphotos",true);
        x.send(formdata);
       } 
   }
   img.src=URL.createObjectURL(this);

}
file.click();
```

or, better, you can create a function that gets the file and returns a promise.

```
function checkSize(fileToCheck) {

  return new Promise( function(resolve, reject) {
    var img = newElement("img",0,"");
    img.onload=function(){
      var cw=img.width;
      var ch=img.height;
      cw<500||ch<500 ? reject() : resolve()
    }
    img.src=URL.createObjectURL(fileToCheck);
  })
}
...
file.onchange=function(e){
  checkSize(this)
  .then( function() { /* success handler */ } )
  .catch( function() { /* error handler */ } )
}
```